# Blocking app from running in bluestacks, youwave and other emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, blocking, bluestacks

I would like to block my app from running in emulators such as bluestacks/youwave etc. Is there anyway I can block or even identify if the user is running in bluestacks/youwave? My app has logging in features. So it users the server as well, so I dont mind blocking the user at clientside/serverside as long as he's blocked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the various values from the `Build` class to see if these emulators have anything distinctive.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for that. After a bit of research, it looks like bluestacks emulator returns null for 'TelephonyManager.getline1number()' . Is that advisable? Would it be blocking the app from many other devices other than tablets?

Comment: "Is that advisable?" -- no, because lots of devices do that. `getLine1Number()` is perhaps the least reliable method in all of Android. Again, I sincerely hope that Bluestacks and kin put something in the `Build` values to identify themselves.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, it sucks that they have made it look exactly like a samsung galaxy device. Messaged them asking for help but no reply. It even has galaxy's certificates installed in it. Is there any method I can block all non phone devices? like tablets etc? I wouldnt mind that as well if it blocks bluestacks

Comment: "It even has galaxy's certificates installed in it." -- that's a bit surprising. "Is there any method I can block all non phone devices? like tablets etc?" -- see what `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` returns. That will return `false` for devices lacking telephony capability.

Comment: @CommonsWare It returned true for 'hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)' . Any other suggestions?
btw..thanks a lott for taking your time to help us out :) Really appreciate it.

Comment: Just curious... Why do you want to block emulators specifically?

Comment: It's likely because users use emulators to 'cheat' by creating fake users for referal rewards

Comment: hi ...did u find any reliable solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

## 1: Check for SIM Number and deny access to whoever has none. This includes tablets since you stated that you wanted to block them.

Java:

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

## 2. Emulator kernel check.

If #1 fails because of user modifications to their emulator, check if (ro.kernel.qemu == 1). This property is read-only and will always return 1 for emulators.